# How to interpret this current/voltage graph of linear regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, graph

Here is a graph from datasheet of XC6202P332 voltage regulator (https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6202/XC6202.pdf):

[image]

What does the lower part of the curve (below 3.3V) mean? Thermal shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regulator has a *foldback current limiter*. Initially, it limits current to a max value of 300mA. As the output voltage decreases further from load (below 2V), it also decreases current (‘folds back’) even more. This limits the dissipation in the device.

It is showing this fold back behavior for three different thermal environments, which actually don’t vary that much. The max current decreases a bit with temperature, but that’s all.

On the other hand, I see no mention of a thermal shutdown in the datasheet.

Further reading: https://www.edn.com/foldback/

Comment: Just a bit more on what hacktastical said.  The reason for the foldback behavior is to reduce the power dissipation in the device.  If it just provided simple current limiting, the max power dissipation may be 1.0 W (300 mA x 3.3 V).  With foldback, the power dissipation for a short condition is around 0.1 W (30 mA x 3.3 V).